# How can I deserialize json to case classes on android?

Tags: android, json, scala

I've tried to use liftweb-json to deserialize json into my case classes and it works fine if I do it in a normal project.

On android, however, liftweb-json cannot match the case class contructors to the json, possibly because Proguard is stripping some information needed for reflection.

Has anyone successfully managed to deserialize to case classes dynamically on android? It doesn't have to be with liftweb-json.

Comment: To work with JSONs i've always used GSON library. Here you will find a good tutorial http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/01/android-json-parsing-gson-tutorial.html =)

Comment: I cant check it right now, but try with Rapture.io library. It has really nice features.

Comment: @Krever Rapture.io was actually the first library I tried, but I couldn't really get it to work even outside of android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've pointed out, the issue is that `lift-json` is using reflection. Unless you plan to carefully correct the proguard file, it'll be very difficult, and a massive time sink.

The better option would be to use a library that doesn't use reflection at all. We've had great success with [argonaut](http://argonaut.io) in our android app. Error messages are great and the compositional API is very elegant.